# BitLocker: CBC vs XTS and FIPS 140-2

Tags: aes, bitlocker

I have a twofold question, first when choosing between AES-CBC and AES-XTS which is more secure. From my reading XTS is more secure in some respects but not in others when compared to CBC. Second are both modes FIPS 140-2 approved? Related to that question if I am using BitLocker on a virtual machine volume with no TPM, only a password would that still be covered? I looked at the following but it didn't really give an answer.

[Is BitLocker on a virtual machine FIPS 140-2 security level 1 compliant?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14411/is-bitlocker-on-a-virtual-machine-fips-140-2-security-level-1-compliant)

Comment: XTS and CBC are NIST approved modes of operation for AES. I would link to their documentation but it seems like due to the US government shutdown, parts of the NIST website (csrc) are inoperable.

Comment: Yeah I ran into the same issue with the links not working, I used Google cache to view them. Still not sure which is "better" or if they would work in a VMware environment or if I would need an external key management server.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750357.aspx) Bitlocker is FIPS 140-2 approved when used with AES-256 *without* the elephant diffuser enabled.  The elephant diffuser is designed to prevent CBC bit-flipping attacks: rather than a bit flip affecting one bit in the subsequent block, it would affect more (50% on average, IIRC).  [NIST CSRC](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp2934.pdf) also lists both CBC and XTS modes as FIPS 140-2 approved, though it's not clear if this applies to all of Bitlocker.

Comment: Thanks, I read something about FIPS wanting the keys stored off the server in some KMS or something else vs on the server using password only? Since its a VMware guest it doesn't have a TPM so I would need to use some kind of virutal TPM or similar to get the key off the system.